# Can LibreOffice Base odb databases migrate to SQL server?

Tags: conversion, export, sql, libreoffice-base

If I make a LibreOffice Base database in its native ODB format, is it possible to later migrate the database to a SQL server such as PostgreSQL??? If so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quick and expensive way is to use [RazorSQL](http://www.razorsql.com/features/hsqldb_export.html), which costs $70, though you can use the free trial if you only need it once. Alternately you can use the SQL window with the command:

```
SCRIPT 'file.sql'
```

You'll get SQL that you can play back into your favorite DBMS. You'll probably need to remove various HSQL-specific bits: The collation and DBA user lines at the top, the SA lines & set write_delay at the bottom, the cached from `CREATE CACHED TABLE`, incompatible names, etc. Oh, and add a semicolon after every statement.

There are various ways to export data to CSV, but export to SQL is almost always preferable if you're going to import it back in to another RDBMS.